# CodeHS JavaScript Timer- Countdown

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I work on CodeHS and need to make a countdown timer for my powerups in the game I'm making, Breakout. I need the timer to be reusable so no for loops, it needs to go down in seconds/milliseconds (it doesn't matter which) and preferably last 30 seconds or 30,000 milliseconds. Remember this is CodeHS I'm working on.

Comment: Please show what you have done (your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to happen 30 seconds after you start your timer you could do something like this:

```
//set the time remaining to 30 outside of a function so it is global
var timeRemaining = 30;

function start(){
//set the timer to run the function countdown once every second(1000 milliseconds)
    setTimer(countdown, 1000)
}

function countdown(){
    /*every time it is called this function subtracts one from the time if it is
    more than 30, when it reaches 0 stops the timer and resets the time*/
    if(timeRemaining<=0){
        stopTimer(countdown);
        timeRemaining = 30;
        println("Done");
        //30 seconds has passed, do what you need here(call your function)
    }else{
        timeRemaining--;
        println(timeRemaining+" seconds left")
    }
}
```

Add your function or whatever you want to happen after the time is up where`println("Done")` is.

Because `timeRemaining` is set back to 30 at the end, you can reuse the timer by calling `setTimer(countdown, 1000)` again.

You can remove the `println` statments, they are just to see what is happening.

If CodeHS doesn't want hardcoded numbers (I think they call them "magic numbers"), replace the 30s with a constant set to 30.

Let me know if you need a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I'm wrong because I have no idea what CodeHS is, but I am quite sure that this can be achieved with a simple `setInterval` function.

**To go by full seconds:**

```
   var timer=30;
    setInterval(function(){
    timer-=1;
    document.getElementById(timerId). innerHTML=timer;//shows the remaining time
    }, 1000);//subtracts 1 second from timer each second
```

**To go by tenths of a second**

```
var timer=30.0;
setInterval(function(){
timer-=0.1;
document.getElementById(timerId). innerHTML=timer;//shows the remaining time
}, 1000);//subtracts a tenth second from timer every 0.1 seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var timeLeft = 60;
var txt = new Text(" ","30pt Arial");

function start(){txt.setPosition(200,200); txt.setColor(Color.black); add(txt); setTimer(countdown,1000);}

function countdown(){drawTimer(); timeLeft--;}

function drawTimer(){txt.setText(timeLeft);}
```